# Avoid loop-recur while transforming a long sequence to a shorter one using a function that could consume an arbitrary number of elements

Tags: clojure

Say there is a list of tokens and a function that consumes an arbitrary number of tokens and returns a statement and the remaining tokens on each invocation. Extracting all statements till all the tokens are exhausted can be done using loop-recur like this:

```
(defn parse
  [code]
  (loop [tokens (lex code)
         statements []]
    (if (empty? tokens)
      statements
      (let [{:keys [remaining-toks statement]} (parse-statement tokens)]
        (recur remaining-toks (conj statements statement))))))
```

Is there any way to accomplish this without the loop-recur?

Comment: Often the other option is a lazy sequence.  But if your code works could you at least elaborate, why you don't want to use the loop/recur?

Comment: @cfrick Here as often, laziness is its own reward. A lazy solution could parse part of the input and then be asked to stop, while loop/recur is stuck slurping it all up even if the first statement is `exit` or whatever.

Comment: The clojure core "partition-by" function is an example of solving this kind of problem.  You can find its source code linked from the API documentation:  https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/partition-by.  The standard library provides both an eager (transducer) and lazy version, so you could model your function on the last 7 lines of it, the lazy part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [lazy-seq](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/lazy-seq) to delay the evaluation of the tail of the output.

```
(defn- parse-tokens [tokens]
  (when (not-empty tokens)
    (let [{:keys [remaining-toks statement]} (parse-statement tokens)]
      (cons statement
            (lazy-seq (parse-tokens remaining-toks))))))

(defn parse [code]
  (parse-tokens (lex code)))
```

Alternatively with [iterate](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/iterate) (assuming that `parse-statement` returns `nil` for empty input):

```
(defn parse [code]
  (->> {:remaining-toks (lex code)}
       (iterate (comp parse-statement :remaining-toks))
       (next)
       (take-while some?)
       (map :statement)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The [design notes on `lazy-seq`](https://clojure.org/reference/lazy#_recipe_how_to_write_lazy_sequence_functions_in_new_model) recommend putting the `cons` inside, which makes all items in the sequence lazily realised, not just the tail items:

```clj
(defn- parse-tokens [tokens]
  (lazy-seq
    (when (seq tokens)
      (let [{:keys [remaining-toks statement]} (parse-statement tokens)]
        (cons statement (parse-tokens remaining-toks))))))

(defn parse [code]
  (parse-tokens (lex code)))
```

Answer (score -2):

Just syntactically without `loop ... recurse` would be:

```
(defn parse-tokens [tokens & {:keys [statements] :or {statements []}}]
  (if (empty? tokens)
      statements
      (let [{:keys [remaining-toks statement]} (parse-statement tokens)]
        (parse-tokens remaining-toks (conj statements statement)))))

(defn parse [code] (parse-tokens (lex code)))
```

Comment: Clojure doesn't do automatic tail call optimisation, so this variant would almost certainly blow the stack for reasonably sized input.